# Python 'textract' library installation failed

Tags: python, pip, text-extraction

Tried to install 'textract' using pip. failed to install the same in windows.

```
pip install textract

ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7_l1veet\EbookLib\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        long_description = open('README.md').read(),
      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1671: character maps to <undefined>
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7_l1veet\EbookLib\
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError installing EBookLib 0.15 for textract 1.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530297/unicodedecodeerror-installing-ebooklib-0-15-for-textract-1-6-1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install textract on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743723/cant-install-textract-on-windows)

Comment: Recommending 'tika' library for textract text from pdf. And it is working in both windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing Anaconda as a package manager and from there you can install Textract using the commands specified in the following link : `https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/textract`

Comment: To be precise: `Anaconda` is not a package manager. It is a python distribution that comes bundled with `conda` which is a package manager.

Comment: Also could you include why you think that completely swithing python distributions is a reasonable suggestion when there are other easy fixes available for this problem?