# How to install textract on Anaconda (Windows 10)?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I'm trying to install Anaconda on Windows but I'm having the following errors:

[Conda: screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVgkS.png)

[Pip install: screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp2eQ.png)

Error messages:

```
(base) C:\Users\vinay>**conda install -c conda-forge textract**

Solving environment: **failed**

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  **- textract**

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, navigate to https://anaconda.org and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install textract on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743723/cant-install-textract-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried installing through pip?
https://pypi.org/project/textract/

`pip install textract`

Comment: yes ,everything is done but at last line this error comes                                 
                                                                                                                    
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\vinay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y1ejkzxz\EbookLib\

Comment: could you please post the full screenshot?

Comment: before the pip command use the below commands to change the encoding.

`REM change CHCP to UTF-8
CHCP 65001`
CLS`

Comment: then how to fix that ?

Comment: refer the below link it might help. https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

Comment: (base) C:\Users>REM change CHCP to UTF-8 CHCP 65001 CLS   :---                                                          Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\vinay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3m061_30\EbookLib\

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problems. I believe that it's because we're using a Windows 64-bit edition, which isn't supported for the anaconda install, as shown below:

[image: Anaconda Textract Screenshot]

As you can see, it only supports win-32. I'm also installing it via the `pip install textract` route as well.