# How to install textract in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to extract from pdf but `pypdf2` doesn't extract all the information and `textract` was unable to install in 3.7 due to following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1671: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743723/cant-install-textract-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the source file for `textract` from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textract
2. `pip3 install pdfminer3k`
3. `untar` the downloaded file
4. `cd` into the directory
5. run: `python3 setup.py install`

Hope it works for you `:)`

Comment: I get "error: Setup script exited with error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1". I cannot install swig

Answer (score 0):

I have installed `textract` on windows 10 with following steps: -

1. `pip install textract`
2. install **poppler**:

   - Download archive - http://blog.alivate.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/poppler-0.68.0_x86.7z
   - Extract it
   - Paste complete folder in `C:\Program Files`
   - Add `C:\Program Files\poppler-0.68.0\bin` to path variable
3. Installation Complete
4. Test by - `import textract`
5. `textract.process('path_to_file_with_extension')`

For further reference, you can [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk6B_wjZLaE)

Hope it will be helpful to you!