# I am getting the error Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed

Tags: python, anaconda, installation, pdftextstream

I was doing text identification and extraction from pdfs and I needed to install textract for that. However I am getting this error while installing:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_get8nd7\EbookLib\
```

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Using anaconda? Have you tried this `conda install -c conda-forge textract`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Comment: @FBlanchet I tried the methods given in the answer, none of them work

Comment: @Dino It gives error that PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - textract

Comment: @KopalSharma looks like [this](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/194#issuecomment-356203467) may fix the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install textract on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743723/cant-install-textract-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: These are the errors I am getting after ugrading pip

Comment: ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Comment: ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rpq_wb98\EbookLib\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        long_description = open('README.md').read(),
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1671: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rpq_wb98\EbookLib\

Comment: You can try to reinstall pip by downloading [this file](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and launch  `python get-pip.py`